# Calculate $\int_0^{\infty} |v(y)| (\int_y^{\infty} e^{-(Im z )(x-y)} dx )dy$ for $Im (z) < 0$ and $\int_0^{\infty} |v(y)| dy = \|v\|$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, operator-theory

This is the crucial part where I am stuck, because it should be  $\int_y^{\infty} e^{-(Im z )(x-y)} dx = C$ so it'll be $C \cdot \|v\|$.

---

That's the whole exercise, we need to show that $R(z;D)$ is a bounded operator for $Im(z) < 0$ in $L_1$ space:

$$\|{R(z; D)v(x)}\| = \int_0^{\infty} |\int_x^{\infty} -i e^{iz(x-y)} v(y) dy|dx \le \int_0^{\infty} (\int_x^{\infty} |-i e^{iz(x-y)} v(y)| dy )dx =$$ $$= \int_0^{\infty} (\int_x^{\infty} |-i| |e^{iz(x-y)}| |v(y)| dy )dx = \int_0^{\infty} (\int_x^{\infty} e^{-(Im z )(x-y)}|v(y)| dy )dx =$$ $$= \int_0^{\infty} |v(y)| (\int_y^{\infty} e^{-(Im z )(x-y)} dx )dy$$

where

$$R(z; D)v(x) = -i \int_x^{\infty} e^{i z(x-y)} v(y) dy, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}_+ \ a.e.$$

Comment: Should work out as $||v||/Im(z)$ when you integrate the $exp(x-y)$ in $x$ and substitute $x=y$ giving $exp(0)=1$. Should be an answer of $-||v||/Im(z)>0$ so check for sign change

Comment: @fGDu94 I don't understand what you want me to do. $\int_y^{\infty} e^{-(Im z)(x-y)} dx$ does not converge for $Im (z) < 0$

Comment: @fGDu94 But where exactly in my calculations should I do what exactly? Could you maybe write this out as an answer?

Comment: I think your expression should be $\int_y^{\infty} e^{+(Im z)(x-y)} dx$ by this point, which accounts for the error

Comment: @fGDu94 This would solve my problem. But: $ |e^{iz(x-y)}| = e^{- Im(z)(x-y)}$, so this solution wouldn't simply be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the integral $ \int_0^{\infty} (\int_x^{\infty} |-i| |e^{iz(x-y)}| |v(y)| dy )dx = \int_0^{\infty} (\int_x^{\infty} e^{-(Im z )(x-y)}|v(y)| dy )dx $

If you want to use Fubini/Tonelli, you should note that when $x\leq y \leq \infty, 0\leq x\leq \infty$, this equates to $0 \leq x \leq y, 0\leq y\leq \infty$, which should help you compute the integral without issues.

Comment: Does that mean that I've applied Fubini in the wrong way here? That instead of $\int_0^{\infty} |v(y)| (\int_y^{\infty} e^{-(Im z )(x-y)} dx )dy$ it should be $\int_0^{\infty} |v(y)| (\int_0^y e^{-(Im z )(x-y)} dx )dy$? I really don't understand this, because it would make matters worse acutally. $\int_0^y e^{ -Im(z) (x-y)} dx = \frac{-1 + e^{y Im(z)}}{Im (z)}$, you've got an $y$ in the result and we don't want that here, what we want is a constant. Though maybe $\frac{-1 + e^{y Im(z)}}{Im (z)} \le \frac{-1}{Im (z)}$ for $y \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Yes this is the inequality I got too, which gives L1 convergence